# How to conditionally find records from mongodb using node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
[ 
  {
   name: 'Some one'
   rep_id: '101',
   user_ids: ['102','103','104']
  },
  {
   name: 'Some one else'
   rep_id: '106',
   user_ids: ['102','103','104','105']
  },
]
```

I want to search records with rep_id from `mongodb`. If rep_id is not matched it should search the same id in user_ids array. If it's not present in user_ids array as well, it should skip that record. I'm able to find with rep_id being matched but how can I do the same if it's not matched and it's present in user_ids array.
From the above records, if rep_id is `101` it should give me the first record and if rep_id is `102` it should give me the both the records since `102` is present in both user_ids array.

Even a hint of the solution will be enough

Comment: why `if rep_id is 102 it should give me the second record since 102 is present in user_ids array` first record also matched what you said. It doesn't make sense

Comment: That's correct, my mistake. It should give me both the records if rep_id is ```102```

Comment: Then I think my answer below is what you need.

Comment: user_ids is an array. Will this logic work ??

Comment: SURE, check mongoplayground below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$or`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          rep_id: "102"
        },
        {
          user_ids: "102"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DEDYbpGeVTL)